Coaching vs therapy for communication problems
My question is about people with mild to moderate communication issues.
Could coaching help in the situation? For example by being around someone (a coach) professional and natural in relationships. By trainings like starting new conversations with total strangers, maybe they can learn (just like a child when growing up) the natural flow of conversations and how one can make the conversations longer or deeper when needed. Maybe it also helps with confidence issues, when they see they can learn communicating and face some progress in it.
Could coaching help here or they just have to go through the therapy road and finding the root cause and solve them somehow...?
